# why are python base64 return values different: open(), StringIO()?

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library

When importing an image I receive a different value than when I create an image.  If I import the image

```
img = open('16x9.gif','rb')
img.read().encode('base64')
# 'R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7\n'
```

But, If I create the image in cStringIO:

```
import cStringIO
import base64
import Image

tmp = cStringIO.StringIO()
img = Image.new('RGB', (16,9))
img.save(tmp, format='GIF', transparency=0)
base64.b64encode(tmp.getvalue())
# Response truncated for readability
# 'R0lGODdhEAAJAIcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADMAAGYAAJkAAMwAAP8AA...
```

The value returned by this second snippet is different and much longer than the first.

Why are my return values different and how do i get the shorter (see first) base64 value?

Comment: Have you made sure the image you create and `16x9.gif` are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, this image was created by python. if I do `img.save('16x9.gif')` then `open()` i get the desired return value.

Comment: @delnan you were right. I had a few images, some created by python, others in photoshop, and they are not the same. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is between those images representations is format, as your first string is a gif in `89a` format, while your tmp is `87a`.

```
>>> 'R0lGODlh'.decode('base64')
'GIF89a'
>>> 'R0lGODdh'.decode('base64')
'GIF87a'
```

The only related discussion on the topic I found is this: [GIF89A and PIL](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/190149/), so it seems that PIL can load `89a` format, but can't create it on his own.

Comment: I have looked at my files and now see that the one I was referencing was not generated by python. But, thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

As @delnan pointed out, I was not using the equivalent image.

But, in my search I found that `png` images return shorter base64 strings than `gif` images.

Closer to what was retuned from a gif that was made in photoshop.